# Go back to ubuntu packages after installing from an external repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 15.10, repository

I had to work with some kali packages, so i added the last kali repository to my file /etc/apt/sources.list . Everything went fine, and I installed some packages and worked with some.

But during the installation of some packages, I have noticed that some already install packages in my Ubuntu were updated to the one who are in the kali repositories. That was fine at the moment, but now when I try to install some packages for Ubuntu, I get the error `Unable to correct problems , defective packets are in mode " keep state "`.

I guess that he problem came from the fact that some Ubuntu packages were update the versions that were in kali repository.

So, how can I kinda unupgrade all my installed packets to the version which are in the Ubuntu repository.

PS : I have already removed kali repository. And I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 with Linux version > 4.

Comment: I recommend you to backup and reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to downgrade packages to the official Ubuntu repositories :

We have to install the package ppa-purge with `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`, who will remove an external repository, and downgrade all packages to the available versions in the official repository.

So `sudo ppa-purge ppa:user/ppa-name` will remove the repository and automatically downgrade the packages.

Answer (score 1):

Determine the first date that you added the Kali repository, and inspect `/var/log/apt/history.log` for packages installed on and after that date. These are the packages that **may** have come from the Kali repository, and that you should reinstall.

It should be a simple matter of editing to transform this list of packages (remove the version information info, 1-entry-per-line, etc), then feed this cleaned up list of packages to `sudo apt-get install --reinstall`. You may have to feed the list of packages to `|xargs sudo apt-get install --reinstall` (see `man xargs`) if there are too many.

Comment: I see, i looked to that log file, and the first entrance is from 2 mars. Too bad, but thanks anyway. There is noway to tell ubuntu to install versions that you find in the repositories now ??!!

Comment: Then look at `/var/log/apt/history.log*`. These gzipped files contain logs back to the Beginning Of Time

Comment: Ah, très très bien, j'ai trouvé les fichiers compressés des logs précédents, et il contient les noms des paquets que j'ai installé précédemment. Merci infiniment.